# Fill an array asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have two arrays here, filling one of them with random numbers:

```
var arr1 = [1];
var arr2 = [];

function arr1Filler() {
    arr2 = arr1;
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            arr1[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
        }
        console.log('array 1:');
        console.log(arr1);
        console.log('array 2:');
        console.log(arr2);
    }, 500);
}

setInterval(arr1Filler, 1000);
```

in this example, why these two arrays are always equal. In other words, why I am getting something like this:

```
array 1:   
[ 3, 0, 1 ]
array 2:   
[ 3, 0, 1 ]
array 1:   
[ 0, 2, 3 ]
array 2:   
[ 0, 2, 3 ]
array 1:   
[ 1, 2, 4 ]
array 2:   
[ 1, 2, 4 ]
```

instead of a result like this (the last value of array 2 is the new value of array 1):

```
array 1:
[ 1 ]
array 2:
[ 3, 0, 1 ]
array 1:
[ 3, 0, 1 ]
array 2:
[ 0, 2, 3 ]
array 1:   
[ 0, 2, 3 ]
array 2:   
[ 1, 2, 4 ]
```

What should I do to get the second result which I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same because you set the arrays to the **same** object here:

```
arr2 = arr1;
```

So when you add to `arr1`, `arr2` is always identical. What you want is a **copy** of `arr1`. You can use `slice` to effectively make a copy of an array.

```
arr2 = arr1.slice();
```

```js
var arr1 = [1];
var arr2 = [];

function arr1Filler() {
    arr2 = arr1.slice();
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            arr1[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
        }
        console.log('array 1:');
        console.log(arr1);
        console.log('array 2:');
        console.log(arr2);
    }, 500);
}

setInterval(arr1Filler, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. can you explain the difference? I'm pretty sure in OOP based languages like java `arr2 = arr1.slice();` means `arr2 = arr1;`. Is this a javascript thing!?

Comment: @Hooman - see [Javascript by reference vs. by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: You would have the same problem in Java. Variables are just pointers to objects in memory. `arr2 = arr1` means "arr2 points to the same object that arr1 points to". In Java you would have `arr2 = arr1.clone()` instead